# Disable Text Cursor in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a DIV as a simple DHTML graphical button on a webpage. It contains no text, and a background image provides the button's appearance. This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE, when the button is clicked a blinking vertical text cursor shows up, presumably where the text line would start. How do I disable this?

I've tried the normal JS and CSS tricks, like binding onstartselect to "function(){ return false; }" and setting "cursor: none;" and "user-select:none;" (which probably isn't supported in IE), but these had no effect. Is there anything else I can do?

EDIT: Yes, by "text cursor" I mean "Caret", or the cursor that indicates the insertion point for your text. For me, if I open ANY page in IE7 and single-click on some text, the caret appears at the position I clicked.

Comment: have a live example to showcase this ?

Comment: Wait, what cursor are you talking about??

Comment: Yeah, if you post the problematic html/css it would be easier to help you arrive at a solution.

Comment: "The Cursor" is the thing that is controlled by the mouse. "The Caret" is the vertical blinking line that represents an insertion point for text entry.  Please be specific as to which you mean.

Comment: @jeffamaphone, The "mouse cursor" is controlled by the mouse. The "text cursor" is not the same thing.

Comment: @Chris S: You're right, they are not the same thing.  I was attempting to tell you what "the text cursor" is actually called.  It's called "the caret".  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646968(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @jeffamaphone, Thank you, I agree, the caret is one term. I just find "text cursor" to be a more common and intuitive term. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(computers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a browser mode called [Caret Browsing](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/new-features.aspx#caret) and can be toggled on/off by pressing F7.

Comment: yeah, I have had the same problem with this and now just press F7 to wiped its away, tks!

Comment: This was not the case. We had an opacity:0 input[type=file] below a span with filename as span content and same size. When clicked the text insertion caret would appear inside the file input and blink (IE11)

Answer (score 0):

If It is a button, for better UI you should set style="cursor:pointer;" to let the user know that's an click area...

Never the less, a cursor must be present in all times, the browser will always render it, whether you specify it or not..

Comment: I think he is referring to that little blinking line that appears whenever you click a textbox, and it's appearing for him when he clicks the div.

Comment: @Marcin, I've took another "read" to the question...your right! Need to think a little to rephrase my answer ;)