# Remove cursor in input box in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I think this may be an IE bug and it's driving me insane. After hitting escape to close the modal window, a blinking cursor appears in the top left corner. This only happens in IE and unfortunately is the only browser I am allowed to develop on. I tried using ng-class and setting different classes with display:none, but that didn't work.

Steps to recreate:

1. Open plnkr in IE
   http://embed.plnkr.co/8397oT/preview
2. start typing anything to see a modal window pop up with an input box
3. hit ESC button and look in top left corner to see the blinking cursor

HTML

```
<div class="ng-modal" ng-show="modal.isOpen">
  <div class="ng-modal-overlay">
    <div class="ng-modal-dialog">
      <div class="ng-modal-dialog-content">
        <input type="text" ng-model="modal.query" class="ng-modal-input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ng-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  ....
}
.ng-modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  ....
}
.ng-modal-dialog {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  ....
}
.ng-modal-dialog-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.ng-modal-input {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 72px;
  font-size: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: because i've done the research and have created a plunker to simulate my problem.

Comment: Please read the first comment above again. **Must be *in* the question, not just linked.** Please also read the help, where it says the same thing. There's also that handy `<>` button (Stack Snippets, runnable HTML/JS/CSS right here on site, with a drop-down letting you add Angular.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3229739/335583 (first result when I search `disable ie textarea cursor`)